# Binding Energy of He

Tags: binding-energy

The graph of nuclear binding energy is relatively smooth going from H to U, except for He4 (alpha particle). Why is He4's binding energy so anomalously high compared to its neighboring isotopes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unusually symmetric.  All four nucleons are in 1s spatial orbitals, in singlet pairs of spin and of isospin.  The more symmetry as system has, the lower its energy.